# Urban Airship iOS Push Notifications Not Received By iOS Device

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I have tried to set up Urban Airship to deliver push notifications to my iOS application with no luck.

Here are the things I have:

- Developer Provisioning profile with push notifications enabled
- Push Notification Certificate on device and uploaded to Urban Airship
- No errors anywhere - UA's error console is empty and I checked that my Device token is active

Here is some snippets from my AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
//Push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];


    //Init Airship launch options
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

    // Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
    // Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

    // Register for notifications
    [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                          UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                          UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    [UAirship setLogging:YES];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    // Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
    NSLog(@"APN device token: %@", devToken);
    [[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:devToken];
}
```

None of the following methods are ever called when I send a notification through UA's "Test Push Notification" tab, or send a CURL command through terminal

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err.description);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Received push notification with userInfo:%@", userInfo);
}
- (void)handleNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification applicationState:(UIApplicationState)state
{
    NSLog(@"Received push notification with notification:%@", notification);
}
```

I have tried sending test push notifications with the app closed and iOS does not do anything either. I checked in Settings on the iphone and went to my app and it shows push is enabled for badges and banners. I'm running iOS 6.1 on an iPhone 5.

Comment: From your description it's not clear whether `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called.

Comment: Yes it IS being called and I see my devices' Device Tokens on UA's website.

Comment: Well, in that case the only problem I can think of it with the certificate. Are you should you uploaded the correct certificate? Are you using a sandbox or production certificate? Is your app signed with a development or ad hoc/production provisioning profile? If the provisioning profile doesn't match the certificate, Apple doesn't send any error indication.

Comment: I uploaded the Development Push SSL Certificate from apple's Provisioning Portal for the AppID I use to sign the application (with the same bundle ID). I use a Development provisioning profile and a Development Push Certificate. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out - I must have missed this line from the documentation:

```
[[UAPush shared] handleNotification:[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
                   applicationState:application.applicationState];
```

Comment: Gr8.I missed that too. +1 for you.Saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. I swear I read over the docs 10s of times and could not see my failure.. It took two days of head banging to discover that I missed 1 line haha.

Comment: Please update this answer as in latest SDK either this is modified OR Removed

Comment: Hi @AbhishekThapliyal would you be so kind as to write another answer? I actually am no longer working on this project but I bet your answer would help future viewers.